# How can I get id of span element inside select element?

Tags: javascript, html

My html form has the content below:

```
<form name="profile">
 ...
 <select id="province" name="province">
  <span id="provinceWarning" class="alert"></span>
  <option value="">Select Province</option>
  <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
   ...
```

In my javascript, I'm trying to grab the form's ID to show a message telling the user to choose something in the dropdownlist if they haven't chosen anything and pressed the submit button. The problem is that the javascript block returns undefined.

```
//validate the profile form
function validate(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var valid=true;


   if(document.profile.province.value == ""){
       document.getElementById('provinceWarning').innerHTML="*Please choose a province*";
       valid=false;
    }

    if(valid){
        alert("Thank You!");
    }

    return valid;

};
```

Comment: Your if statement looks weird to me, I'm pretty sure you need a selector (document.getElementBy...) and then grab the value of it

Comment: i updated the javascript part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it comes down and reset once u select and submit.

```js
function submit(){
  if(!document.getElementById("province").value){

  document.getElementById("provinceWarning").innerHTML="*Please choose a Province*";
    valid=false;
}else{
  document.getElementById("provinceWarning").innerHTML=""
  valid=true;
  window.alert("thank you")
}
}
```

```html
<form name="profile">
 <select id="province" name="province">
  <option value="">Select Province</option>
  <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
 </select>
 <span id="provinceWarning" class="alert"></span>
</form>
<button id="btnSubmit" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Yours helped me fix the location of the message issue. Putting the span right under the end of the select element fixed it without any css or div.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a `span` tag inside a `select` tag. Browser while rendering this HTML would have stripped it off.

**See the demo below** (check in your **browser's dev tools** that browser is *stripping off span tag* while rendering)

```html
<select id="province" name="province">
  <span id="provinceWarning" class="alert"></span>
  <option value="">Select Province</option>
  <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
</select>
```

You need to put the `span` tag outside the `select` tag.

Comment: Thanks the message shows but it's to the left and messes up the dropdown list format

Comment: @answerSeeker which message is showing, `span`'s text? Which browser are you testing this on? You shouldn't be putting `span` inside `select` since it is not supported as per standard.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1- You can not define `span` in `select` option then move it out of your select

2- To check select value you should `getElementById("province")` and then check the value

3- Testable code can be as below(You can change it as you want):

```js
function func()
{
   var ddl = document.getElementById("province");
   var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value; 
   if (selectedValue  == ""){
    document.getElementById("provinceWarning").innerHTML="*Please choose a Province*";
    valid=false;
   }else{
    alert("Thank You!");
   }
}
```

```html
<form name="profile"> 
 <div>
   <span id="provinceWarning" class="alert"></span>
 </div>
 <div>
   <select id="province" name="province"> 
     <option value="">Select Province</option>
    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 </form>
 <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="func();">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to make the message show up on the right instead?

Comment: @answerSeeker, Did you run code snippet here, did you see the output ?

Comment: yes, it puts it at the top of the select province dropdown. I guess I'll have to fix this with some css

Comment: @answerSeeker, Yes you can decorate it, then if you think it helped you please accept it as answer.

Comment: You want it be at the right of select option, like before my edit ? just remove the `div` for `span` and `select`, or you can decorate it by Css as you want.